# What is the translation for terms associated with "predatory lending"?

Tags: translation

*Predatory lending* is usually associated with 'loan-sharks' who trap a *borrower* into a circumstance where he will likely encounter difficulty in repayment. Usually, the borrower finds himself in a hole that continues to become 'deeper'.

*Predatory lending* is also associated with *debt-bondage* where the borrower's debt is sold to another party who will utilise the borrower's labour to repay the debt.

What is the translation for the following terms:

- The concept of "predatory lending"
- A person who practices predatory lending (the lender)
- The person who is trapped by predatory lending
  (the borrower)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see online dictionaries, iciba:predatory lending 掠夺性贷款 http://www.iciba.com/predatory%20lending find 2 examples sentences, predatory lender 掠夺性贷款人 victim of pred. lending 掠夺性贷款(的)受害人/者，for confirmation submit 掠夺性 to bkrs: 掠夺性贷款；高利贷 predatory credit practice

additional relevant vocabulary at https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%8E%A0%E5%A4%BA%E6%80%A7%E8%B4%B7%E6%AC%BE https://wiki.mbalib.com/wiki/%E6%8E%A0%E5%A4%BA%E6%80%A7%E8%B4%B7%E6%AC%BE

Answer (score 1):

A very common term is [高利貸](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000068808) in Taiwan.

高: high
利: interest
貸: loan

It's also called 高利盤剝, 閻王債 or [印子錢](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000157143).

The shop is named [地下錢莊](https://www.moedict.tw/%E5%9C%B0%E4%B8%8B%E9%8C%A2%E8%8E%8A).